# Branch-free implementation of f(x) := if x == 0 then 0 else (x * log(x))

Tags: c, optimization, nan, logarithm, branch-prediction

I have this C function:

```
double f(int x)
{
    if (x <= 0)
        return 0.0;
    else
        return x * log(x);
}
```

which I am calling in a tight loop, and would like to get rid of the branch to see if it improves performance.

I cannot use this:

```
double f(int x)
{
    return x * log(x);
}
```

because it returns `NaN` when `x == 0` (which is true about 25% of the time.)

Is there another way to implement it so that it returns `0` when `x == 0`, but still get rid of the branch?

(I am less concerned about negative inputs, because these are errors, whereas zeros are not.)

Comment: `?: ` is also branching but if you want to get rid of `if-else` then you can use it

Comment: Is there a reasonably finite range of values for `x`, or is it more or less unconstrained?

Comment: @Omkant: It is the actual branching I am concerned about, not the syntax.

Comment: @meagar: it can be anything between 0 and 2^52

Comment: Well, you *do* have a piecewise function. It's hard to imagine how to evaluate it without a condition on the pieces. But check your assembly, which may replace the branch by a conditional-move anyway.

Comment: Performance of this calculation is going to be completely dominated by `log`.  Therefore, you *want* the branch in there, because you don't want to call `log` if you're going to throw away the answer.

Comment: Logarithm is implemented as a function on x86-64. It's unlikely that not branching but calling the expensive function always brings more than branching and occassionally not calling it.

Comment: For the purposes of testing performance, just replace the function with `return x * log(x)`. That gives the wrong answer, sure, but it's no slower than whatever branch-free code you could possibly come up with. So unless it's dramatically faster than what you have, you can stop. There's no need to actually come up with the branch-free code because you've established that it won't help.

Comment: @meagar: small values (≤20) are much more common than larger values though, so if I am going to have the branch anyway it might be worth keeping them in a table.  Is that what you were thinking of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any branch free code must contain a calculation of `x * log(x)` to cover the "normal" case.

So, before trying to come up with that branch-free code, measure the speed of `x * log(x)` alone. Unless it's significantly faster than the code you have, there's nothing significant to be gained here. And I suspect it won't be.

Answer (score 13):

First note that *log(1) = 0*. Then you can write the problem as x * log(y), where y = 1 if x <= 0, and otherwise equals x; if y = 1, then x doesn't matter, because log(y)=0.

Something like y = (x > 0)*x + (x <= 0) will do this, and then:

```
double f(int x) {
    return x * log((x > 0)*x + (x <= 0));
}
```

It just depends on whether log(1) and four integer ops are worse than a branch.

Comment: Works. As you said, it's probably a lot slower than a branch. It does provide a perfect answer to the OP's question, though, so +1.

Comment: I'd be curious if log(1) is a special case that bails out early. Even then, though, the two comparisons, add, and multiply may take longer than a branch.

Comment: Of course it's down to the compiler whether this code is actually branch-free or not, but it has the nice feature of looking like it might be ;-)

Comment: But where would a compiler get a branch out of this? From the comparison operators?

Comment: @Hodapp: correct. x86 has `setle` and `setg` conditional instructions, ARM allows all instructions to be conditional, but not every architecture does.

Comment: a minor variant would be to cache the comparison: `double f(int x) { int b = x > 0; return x * log(b*x + (1-b)); }`. Almost certainly makes no difference here, but may be helpful in other circumstances where the condition `b` is more complex.

Answer (score 11):

Compiler extensions can help here. In GCC, you would do this:

```
if(__builtin_expect(x > 0, 1)) {
    return x * log(x);
}
return 0.0;
```

GCC will then generate machine code that favors the `x > 0 == 1` branch.

If you don't care about negative numbers, then you can treat `x == 0` as an unlikely branch instead:

```
if(__builtin_expect(x == 0, 0)) {
    return 0.0;
}
return x * log(x);
```

If you're not on GCC, you should check the documentation of your compiler and see whether it provides an analogous feature.

Note that it's still not branch-free. It's just that the likely branch takes less time.

Comment: When `x` is 0 “true about 25% of the time”, I do not think that favoring `x > 0` helps.

Comment: @PascalCuoq If `x` is <=0 25% of the time, then it's >0 75% of the time. So that's what favored here. At least that's how I understood the question.

Comment: This gets rid of the jump in the more frequent case, but not of the branch, as I [understand the term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science)). It probably still helps the OP, so I'm upvoting.